# How to Debug Visual Studio Workflows? I have issue with debugging

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am using Visual studio 2019. When i am trying to debug the SharePoint hosted Add-In solutions with SharePoint Online sites, It suddenly stopping the debug process and i am not getting any error during this process. In my solution i am having visual studio workflows and some script files.

Could you please let me know, is there any settings that i need to change it from my end on visual studio?